# Neural network weights explode in linear unit

Tags: numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

I am currently implementing a simple neural network and the backprop algorithm in Python with numpy. I have already tested my backprop method using central differences and the resulting gradient is equal.

However, the network fails to approximate a simple sine curve. The network hast one hidden layer (100 neurons) with tanh activation functions and a output layer with a linear activation function. Each unit hast also a bias input. The training is done by simple gradient descent with a learning rate of 0.2.

The problem arises from the gradient, which gets with every epoch larger, but I don't know why? Further, the problem is unchanged, if I decrease the learning rate.

EDIT: I have uploaded the code to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/R7tviZUJ

Comment: This is a good, well-articulated question. Unfortunately, it feels off-topic for this site. If it gets closed, consider asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try, maybe in combination:

1. Use a smaller learning rate. If it is too high, you may be overshooting the minimum in the current direction by a lot, and so your weights will keep getting larger.
2. Use smaller initial weights. This is related to the first item. A smaller learning rate would fix this as well.

Comment: I already tried that. Unfortunately the gradient "explodes" nevertheless, just slower. If the steps would be to big, the gradient should oscilate? But it gets bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (with a different library, DL4J), even in the case of extremely simple target functions.  [In my case, the issue turned out to be the cost function.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258587)  When I changed from negative log likelihood to Poisson or L2, I started to get decent results.  (And my results got MUCH better once I added exponential learning rate decay.)

Comment: I'm seeing something similar trying to train a network to do linear regression.  I did add learning rate decay in, which allows me to hit the mark (my test data has a known slope of .5), but I worry that adding in the decay is covering up a bug in the network, that the weights should converge and stay converged naturally, especially with an extremely small learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont use regularization. If you train your network long enough it will start to learn the excact data rather than abstract pattern.

There are a couple of method to regularize your network like: stopped training, put a high cost to large gradients or more complex like e.g.g drop out. If you search web/books you probably will find many options for this.

Comment: The overfitting would not be the problem, but my network delivers too big outputs. So instead of the values in [-1, 1] I get values larger then 1e60.

Answer (score 0):

A too big learning rate can fail to converge, and even DIVERGE, that is the point.

The gradient could diverge for this reason: when exceeding the position of the minima, the resulting point could not only be a bit further, but could even be at a greater distance than initially, but the other side. Repeat the process, and it will continue to diverge. in other words, the variation rate around the optimal position could be just to big compared to the learning rate.

Source: my understanding of the following video (watch near 7:30). 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn8qXpIcdnI&list=PLLH73N9cB21V_O2JqILVX557BST2cqJw4&index=10